# Change letters according to a Key (Encryption)

Tags: arrays, c, string, nested-loops, cs50

I'm trying to encrypt a input from the user (variable text) by a cyphertext with a given key (variable argv[1]). Where A is replaced by the first letter of the key, B is replaced by the second letter of the key etc.

For example if I input in the terminal:
`~./test YTNSHKVEFXRBAUQZCLWDMIPGJO`

And the user types in the following text `text: OVERFLOW`

The output is: `ciphertext: QIHLKBQP`

My problem is now that my function does not work for the following user input: `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` with the key `./test DWUSXNPQKEGCZFJBTLYROHIAVM`

What I get:
`ciphertext: Rqx tokug wljif nja eozby jhxl rqx c`

What I want to get:
`ciphertext: Rqx tokug wljif nja eozby jhxl rqx cdmv sjp`

Why does my code stop replacing the letters after the reaching the c and stops adding `"... cdmw sjp"?`

My current code is:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>



int l = 97;
int j = 65;
int difference;
int differencee;
int k=0,b, c;



int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string text = get_string("Plaintext: ");     // Asking for the text-input


    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++, j++, l++) //loop for the given text length
    {
        difference = argv[1][i] - j;
        differencee = argv[1][i] - l;

            if(j==text[k] && text[k]<91 && text[k]>64) // Check for UPPERCASE LETTERS and change according to key
            {
                b = text[k] + difference;

                k++;
                printf("%c",toupper(b));
                i = 0;
                j = 64 +1;
                l = 96 + 1;
            }
            if(l==text[k] && text[k]<123 && text[k]>96)   //Check for LOWERCASE LETTERS and change according to key
            {
                c = text[k] + differencee;

                k++;
                printf("%c",tolower(c));
                i = 0;
                l = 96 + 1;
                j = 64 + 1;
            }
            if(isalpha(text[k]) == 0 && text[k] != '\0') //If not alphabet, then do nothing
            {
                printf("%c",text[k]);
                k++;
                i = 0;
                
            }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: In order to check characters use the form `if (ch >= 'a')` instead of `if (ch > 64)`. It is more portable and readable.

Comment: Even better, if you are allowed to use it, you can use [isalpha](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/ctype.h/isalpha) function.

Comment: Are you sure that after calculations such as `b = text[k] + difference;` b is  still in the printable characters range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your algorithm simply. No need to extra computation and variables.

Check this for your example and change it to cover your work:
Input and output is as your desired.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char text[64] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\0";     // Asking for the text-input

    char argv[32] = "DWUSXNPQKEGCZFJBTLYROHIAVM";
    int len = strlen(argv);
    int i=0;
    char temp = 0;
    int index = 0;
    printf("strlen(text): %d strlen(argv) = %d\n ",strlen(text),len);
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) //loop for the given text length
    {   
        if(isalpha(text[i]) == 0 && text[i] != '\0') //If not alphabet, then do nothing
        {
            printf("%c",text[i]);
            continue;
        }
            
        temp = text[i];
        
        if(temp >= 'A' && temp <= 'Z') // Check for UPPERCASE LETTERS and change according to key
        {
            temp +=32;
        }
            
        if(temp >= 'a' && temp <= 'z')   //Check for LOWERCASE LETTERS and change according to key
        {
            index = (temp - 'a')%len;
            printf("%c",argv[index]);
        }
            
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

EDITTED:
[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/SyXAUNebD)

Comment: As I suggested to OP, above, you should use explicit characters to check alphabetical ranges, instead of _magic numbers_. For example `if (temp >= 'a' && temp <= 'z'). For the conversion you can call `tolower ()`, and call it anyway. In this way the range check won't be necessary anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot @majid, especially for the Online Demo. I could use it for debugging my code and finding my faulty code!

Comment: Also @RobertoCaboni, I have used your advice and changed the code to characters, instead of numbers.

Comment: @Roberto I replaced letters instead of asci codes. Thanks for comment.